# Anyone had success customizing the cardboard mode of the GCSVideoView in the Google Cardboard SDK for iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, sdk, google-cardboard

In a nutshell, I have the latest Google Cardboard SDK for iOS and everything works great in my app except I need to be able to overlay some buttons on top of the stereoscopic cardboard mode of the GCSVideoView. Currently you can overlay things on top of the GCSVideoView, however this is not the case when cardboard mode is triggered.

I believe when you trigger the cardboard mode from the GCSVideoView it generates an external viewcontroller that is a modal on top of the GCSVideoView. So essentially a child of the parent GCSVideoView which I need to access via its parent.

Any advice on how to hack this to get it to do what I want?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just to update you all, we contacted Google and they said they would be releasing a newer SDK that allows more customization. Unfortunately they didn't say when they would be releasing it.